# Given sequence of integers a(1),a(2), a(n). Create a new sequence through replacing all a(i) by 1, if |a(i)=max (a(1),a(2),a(n)); or by 0 otherwise

Tags: c++, arrays

I already have some code, but my lecturer told that it is comparing only the first integer in the array, and negative numbers are not taking into consideration

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int max, n, check;    //declaring variables
    check = 1;
    while (check == 1) {     //programm executes repitedly
        cout << "Enter array element count: ";
        cin >> n;             //user inputs number of elements in array
        if (n <= 0)            //check that number should be bigger then 0
            cout << "Please enter number greater then 0";
        int array[n];           //declaring an array
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {      //entering numbers to array
            cout << "Enter number: ";
            cin >> array[i];
            if (max < array[i]) {            //assigning the biggest number of array as max
                max = array[i];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {      //assigning value to max==1
            if (array[i] == max) {
                array[i] = 1;
            }
            else {                            // to other value assigning 0
                array[i] = 0;
            }
            cout << array[i];                   //showing the results
        }
        cout << "\n1 - continue, 0 - end\n";
        cin >> check;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you have a precise error description from your lecturer? Why not fix that? Also, please provide a [mcve] (mostly okay, still requires manual input) which is consistently formatted (not okay) along with the expected and actual outcome. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: VLA `int array[n];` is not valid C++, use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Remarks of your lecturer are strange as doesn't match with current code, but `max` isn't initialized, leading o UB.

Answer (score 2):

We are here to help.

So let me frist try to compile your code. This is the result of my C++ compiler:

[image: Compiler errors]

So, we can see already now several things. The VLA (Variable Length Array) `int array[n]`is invalid C++ code. VLA's are not a part of the C++ language and connot be used. Additionally the compiler shows the problem with the not initialized varaibale `max'. If may has no value, then the behaviour of you program is undefined.

Strong recommendation. Please swicth always all compiler warnings on. Example: -Werror -Wall -Wpedantic. And fix all warnings.

OK, the lets try to get rid of the problems. First the VLA. A VLA can always be replaced by a `std::vector`. This is a dynamic array, that can grow as needed. But then I hoften hear from students that they did not learn about `vector`. This basically means that the teacher should be fired, but maybe it is a strategic decision to first teach the students the usage of raw pointer for owned memory and new, which is basically banned in C++. But Ok, let us use this approach. We must not forget to delete the allocated memory at the end.

And the variable "max" must be initialized. We will use the minimum possible value here, so that we can make sure, that everything else will be bigger then this initial value.

In the header `<limits>`, we can find all what we need. Please look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits).

Result is this already working program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int max=std::numeric_limits<int>::min(), n, check;    //declaring variables
    check = 1;
    while (check == 1) {     //programm executes repitedly
        cout << "Enter array element count: ";
        cin >> n;             //user inputs number of elements in array
        if (n <= 0)            //check that number should be bigger then 0
            cout << "Please enter number greater then 0";
        int *array = new int[n];           //declaring an array
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {      //entering numbers to array
            cout << "Enter number: ";
            cin >> array[i];
            if (max < array[i]) {            //assigning the biggest number of array as max
                max = array[i];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {      //assigning value to max==1
            if (array[i] == max) {
                array[i] = 1;
            }
            else {                            // to other value assigning 0
                array[i] = 0;
            }
            cout << array[i];                   //showing the results
        }
        cout << "\n1 - continue, 0 - end\n";
        cin >> check;
        delete[] array;
    }
}
```

There are many more things that should be checked. Especially the validation of unser input is important. A little bit more robust version would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {

    // We will rund the program until somebody sets this variable to false
    bool runProgram = true;
    while (runProgram) {

        // Instruction to use, to enter the number of elements to check
        std::cout << "\nEnter array element count: ";

        // Get the number of elements and check, if the we got a valid number
        unsigned int arrayElementCount = 0;
        if ((std::cin >> arrayElementCount) and (arrayElementCount > 0u)) {

            // OK we got a valid number. Now allocate memory for our array.
            int* array = new int[arrayElementCount];

            // We want to find the max value for all values. Therefore we will initialie the initial value with min
            int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();

            // In a loop, get user input, store in array and check for max
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < arrayElementCount; ++i) {      

                // We want to check, if the user enters a valid number or some nonesend like "abc"
                // So, we will read as long the number is not valid
                bool numberIsValid = false;
                while (not numberIsValid) {

                    // Instruction to user to enter number i
                    std::cout << "Enter number '" << i + 1 << "' :\t";

                    // Try to read a valid number
                    if (std::cin >> array[i]) {

                        // Oke, noe we have a valid number. We do not need to read again
                        numberIsValid = true;

                        // CHeck for a new maximum
                        if (max < array[i]) {     
                            max = array[i];
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        // We got a bad number. std::cin is in error state and the input buffer contains garbage
                        // Show error message
                        std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Invalid input. Please try again\n\n";
                        std::cin.clear(); // Reset error flages of std::cin and remove still existing garbage from the input buffer
                        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                    }
                }
            }
            // We want to show the result
            std::cout << "\n\nResult:\n\n";
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < arrayElementCount; i++) {

                // For a max value we will write a 1 to our array
                if (array[i] == max) {
                    array[i] = 1;
                }
                else {                            
                    // To other value assign a 0
                    array[i] = 0;
                }
                // And output restult
                std::cout << array[i] << ' ';                   
            }

            // Ask user, if he wants to continue
            std::cout << "\n\n\n1 - continue program, 0 - end program\n";

            // Get decision of user
            int check = 0;
            // In case of error or other input than 1, end program
            if (not (std::cin >> check) or (check != 1))
                runProgram = false;

            // Release previously allocated memory
            delete[] array;
        }
        else {
            // Error while getting the number of elements for the array
            std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Problem with the input of the element count\n\n";
            std::cin.clear();// Reset error flags of std::cin and remove still existing garbage from the input buffer
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    }
}
```

In case of questions, please ask in the comment

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply. I have a question- how to make that if i enter -7,5,7 I got 101( meaning that negative values are converted into positive, we are using module of -7 which is 7)

Comment: Sorry, I do not fully understand. The program that I posted shows 0 0 1 as output for -7,5,7. Or do you expect to get 1 0 1 as output. In that case you would need to write `if (std::abs(array[i]) == max) {`. But, I am not sure what you mean . . .

Comment: yes, I expected to get 1 0 1 output, can i just use this code?

Comment: if(array[i]<0)
    { array[i] = abs(array[i]);
    }

Comment: Yes, sure. But you can save the if. Writing ` array[i] = abs(array[i]); `  is sufficient